# Should an header file with implementations be linked?

Tags: c++, header

I've a still small header containing implementations. Is it good to compile it to an object and link it among other sources? ... What if it had template functions... ?

Comment: No, never compile and link header files. That would screw up you build system.

Comment: @user0042 Not sure... What if I duplicated my definitions in the final object?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? Just don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your header will be fully included in a source file when it does `#include <yourheader>` and the code will be compiled as part of the including translation unit. So no, there is no reason to compile the header as its own object file/translation unit (and hence, no reason to link it explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it good to compile it to an object and link it among other sources?

No, you shouldn't ever need to compile header files stand alone.

If these contain function implementations you can mark these `static inline` to avoid violating the ODR. Otherwise consider to separate the implementations out into another translation unit.

> ... What if it had template functions... ?

In that case you are required to provide the implementation in the header file.

Answer (score -1):

Well it depends on what you want to achieve. I once had a compiler for an embedded processor that didn't include a linker. In order to have my code distributed over several files I had to #include .c files. In that case it's still very important to use the #ifndef FILENAME_C/#define FILENAME_C protection to avoid including it multiple times.

In other words, for the compiler it does not matter if some code is implemented in a .h or .c file. All it sees is the output of the preprocessor and it's your job to use #includes to generate something the compiler understands.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of this. However, after reading Makefile Overview, I've seen that files are compiled independently of others in 1st example, so that shouldn't change. No sense though: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.pdf

Comment: How does this answer the question??

Comment: Makefiles have default rules to compile .c files to .o files. If you stick to the convention of just compiling .c files and including .h files where necessary, you could make use of these default rules.

Comment: I just commented wrong URL. Here, http://ecee.colorado.edu/~mcclurel/gnu_make_overview.pdf I've not heard much of default rules in this case. Gotta search them all

Comment: I think I'll create ask another question in this case, thanks